# Could not load file or assembly after deploy

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dll

I am developing app, which uses PDFLibNet.dll, everythings works fine on my pc, but when I deploy application and try to use it in another pc, creating PDFWrapper class (from PFDLibNet.dll) throw me an exception: 
Could not load file or assembly "PDFLibNet.dll" or one of its dependencies.The specified module could not be found.

The same scenario on Win7 and XP

PDFLibNet.dll is stored in the same directory as binary .exe file of my app.
Any suggestion how to fix it?
I am using .Net4.0, Win7 
Thanks!

Comment: @Martin Ch... i'm using PDFLibNet dll for .NET3.5... now i need for .NET4.0 could you send it to me?... reply here....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be 2 possible reasons:
1. Check if dll was build for x86 or x64 or AnyCPU if you target machine x64 build your dll x64
2. It can be because of MS C++ redistrubute updates! uninstall them and try to start app again. Or you can either install the redistributable on the target machine.

Comment: THANKS A LOT, it was missing MS C++ 2010 redistribute, I spend an hours finding solutions and then I just install it and it works, what a pitty! thanks :)